# How do I get rid of this SATARaid screen on boot?

Tags: raid, sata, supermicro, hba

I have a server with a SuperMicro X8SIL-V motherboard. Here's [the manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/3420/MNL-1130.pdf). Every time it boots, it spends about three minutes at this screen:

```
Sil 3124 SATARaid BIOS Version 6.3.18
Copyright (C) 1997-2006 Silicon Image, Inc.

Press (Ctrl+S) or F4 to enter RAID utility
```

After that it beeps once and then boots normally.

I have multiple HBA expansion cards in it, but none are hooked up to any drives at the moment. The only drive is a 120GB ssd with a base install of Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the offending HBA. At least until you have drives to connect to it.